# AuditorAware for @Document or @Entity before sending to queue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud-stream

I am looking on a way to enable Audit in spring-data but instead of saving to Db before sending it to queue using `spring-clould-stream` .

My back-end services are not secure so i don't have any idea of who did send this request thus i am not able to implement `AuditorAware`.

I was thinking if their is a listener that we can use to update the `@CreatedBy` and `@LastModifiedBy` before pushing it to cloud-stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream uses Spring Integration as a programming model, so you can use a message channel interceptor: see http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-interceptors .

Answer (score 0):

you can enable auditing for Document or Entity by annotation with `@EnableMongoAuditing` or `@EnableJpaAuditing` and follow the steps from this [article](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-auditing-part-one/)

Comment: `@EnableJpaAuditing` and `@EnableMongoAuditing` depend on `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` . my question is do we have some thing similar to this in spring-cloud-stream may be `@beforeSend`